# Is impossible to install openastro.org package due missing python-dateutil, python-rsvg and imagemagick packages

Tags: apt

Having trouble with installing openastro in my pc.

```
$ sudo apt-get install openastro.org 
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openastro.org : Depends: python-dateutil but it is not installable
                 Depends: python-rsvg but it is not installable
                 Depends: imagemagick but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux user-Lenovo-B580 3.13.0-67-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 23 13:24:41 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`apt-cache policy openastro.org python-dateutil python-rsvg imagemagick`

```
openastro.org:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.1.48-0ubuntu1~trusty
  Version table:
     1.1.48-0ubuntu1~trusty 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pellesimon/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
python-dateutil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
python-rsvg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
imagemagick:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

---

did

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pellesimon/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openastro.org
```

and still got no solution

```
$ sudo apt-get install openastro.org 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openastro.org : Depends: python-dateutil but it is not installable
                 Depends: python-rsvg but it is not installable
                 Depends: imagemagick but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a; uname -a; apt-cache policy openastro.org  python-dateutil python-rsvg  imagemagick`

Comment: when i try to install imagemagik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `apt-cache policy python-dateutil python-rsvg imagemagick` says

```
python-dateutil:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
python-rsvg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
imagemagick:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

- That means either that `main` repository is not enabled or you never ran `sudo apt-get update`.

**OR**

- There was an error message during `apt-get update` (which you provided later):

  ```
  W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
  E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
  ```

  and indeed you [get the information](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/universe/binary-amd64/)

  ```
  Index of /ubuntu/dists/wily/universe/binary-amd64
  [ICO]   Name            Last modified       Size
  [DIR]   Parent Directory        -
  [ ]     Packages.bz2    22-Oct-2015 12:48   6.4M
  [ ]     Packages.gz     22-Oct-2015 12:48   8.3M
  [ ]     Release         22-Oct-2015 12:48   98
  ```

  There is no `Packages` file. But the APT documentation says:

  > APT will then import the list of packages published by each of these […means `sources.list`…] sources. This operation is achieved by downloading Packages.xz or a variant using a different compression method (such as Packages.gz or .bz2) files (in case of a source of binary packages)

  <sub>[Source](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/apt.html)</sub>

Other strange things are, only the universe repository and sometimes the multiverse repository has problems, and from time to time you have a "Hash Sum mismatch" error.

---

You could install the packages manually

```
mkdir ~/openastro
cd ~/openastro
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-dateutil/python-dateutil_1.5+dfsg-1ubuntu1_all.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-python-desktop/python-rsvg_2.32.0+dfsg-3_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/imagemagick_6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

But that's a hard way, you have to download and install each missing and not installable dependency in the same way.

1. Search the Trusty package for 64-bit [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)
2. Download with `wget <URL>`
3. Install with `sudo dpkg -i <DEB_FILE_NAME>`

---

Or try [Tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor), I suspect, you have a problem with your provider and/or country restrictions:

```
sudo apt-get install tor
sudo apt-get install torsocks
```

If the commands above doesn't work, download and install with `dpkg`

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tor/tor_0.2.4.27-1build0.14.04.‌​1_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/torsocks/torsocks_1.3-3_amd64.d‌​eb
sudo dpkg -i tor*.deb
```

Now update and install

```
sudo torify apt-get update
sudo torify apt-get install openastro.org
```

Answer (score 1):

Try installing this way.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pellesimon/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openastro.org
```